# Jython import statements with JSR-223

Tags: java, jython, jsr223

How can we use external Jython modules with JSR-223? (Assuming some foo python module is installed using pip or easy_install and the following Python code is running with Jython)

Python code: (jsr223_test.py)

```
import pyfoo

pyfoo.do_sth()
```

Java code:

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.python.core.Py;
import org.python.core.PySystemState;

public class Main() {
    //BEGIN EDIT
    PySystemState engineSys = new PySystemState();
    engineSys.path.append(".");
    Py.setSystemState(engineSys);
    //END EDIT
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine jython = mgr.getEngineByName("jython");
    jython.eval(new FileReader(new File("jsr223_test.py")));        
}
```

This results in ImportError: no module named pyfoo. However executing the following in a terminal succeeds.

```
jython jsr223_test.py
```

Any advice?

**Edit:**
I guessed it was a classpath issue and copied the py files from the eggs to my applications working directory. Following the http://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#using-jsr-223 I've also added that path to the engine environment (as seen on the code, between //BEGIN EDIT and //END EDIT) and it worked. 
I've also tried adding $JYTHON_HOME/Lib/site-packages to the path but it did not work, I don't know why.